# Missing words in English

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives

For a while I ponder on some words that I have not been able to find.
I always wondered why, since English is so huge compared to my native Danish where we *do* have the following two words:

1. A word for a 24-hour period. I found the Greek one: [*nychthemeron*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nychthemeron). "It is sometimes used, especially in technical literature, to avoid the ambiguity inherent in the term *day*."
   I of course know the word *day* which we have in Danish too, but we also (along with other languages) have a specific word for a 24-hour period.
2. The adjective of *solidarity* — so we have *sympathetic* but not *solidaric* — can anyone tell me why we can be sympathetic to a cause but have to show solidarity?
   Is *solidary* to *solidarity* what *sympathetic* is to *sympathy*? Any usage examples?
   I am interested in any etymologic reason why it is not *solidaric* (Greek root versus French root?)

In Danish I can say *I am solidaric to your cause*.
I cannot hear myself saying *I am solidary to your cause*.

Comment: [Lexical gaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_gap) and [untranslatability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Untranslatability). 'Nuff said.

Comment: Which Latin do you refer to? Did the notion of hour exist in times of Latin formation and active usage (to speak about 24 hours)?

Comment: Of course they did, however the word I used is Greek. Thanks for making me notice

Comment: Funny, we have words for those in Dutch too: *etmaal* and *solidair*.

Comment: English *day* means 'a 24-hour period'. To refer specifically and unequivocally to a 24-hour period starting and stopping and midnight, you need to use something like *calendar day*.

Comment: @Marthaª English *day* also means the period between dawn and dusk.  If for some reason you are restricted to day-driving only, you can’t weasel out of it by claiming that the night is part of the day; it isn’t.

Comment: "I worked 24 hours a day, and if that wasn't enough, I worked at night as well" :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your first point I found words such as [*hemeral*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hemeral) and [*circadian*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/circadian), though there are more concept centered around a 24-hour period, but simply using the word *day*, as suggested by @FX_ would be the way to go, although ambiguous, but [there doesn't seems to be another "English" word which would fit the bill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day#24_hours_vs_daytime).

On the second point, you have the word *solidary*, but also [*solidarily*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/solidarily), which is an adverb defined as "showing solidarity". As such, we can safely assume that *solidary* is the adjective for the same concept.

**EDIT**: As for the fact that *solidary* against *sympathetic*, *sympathetic* comes from the Latin [*sympatheticus*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sympathetic) and sympathy has its own Latin words [*sympathia*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sympathy), both of each having Ancient Greek origin (*sympathetikos* and *sympatheia*), while both *solidary* and *solidarity* comes from the French [*solidaire*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=solidary) which itself comes from the french word *solide* which has its roots in the Latin [*solidus*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=solid), but this time not in the Greek.

Comment: Not Greek sumpathtikos, from sumpatheia ?

Comment: @mplungjan yes, they only did a stop in the Latin vocabulary meanwhile. I will add this precision though.

Answer (score 4):

1. ***day** (noun) 1. a period of twenty-four hours as a unit*; if you want to refer to the natural rhythm of 24 hour period, the adjective is ***circadian***
2. ***solidary** (adjective) (of a group or community) characterized by solidarity or coincidence of interests*

   - “Judge imposes ‘solidary bail’ for poor respondents”
   - “Incentives for a solidary globalization”
   - “Repression and solidary cultures of resistance”

Comment: Please provide the name of where you got these copy-pasted citations from, and a link if available.  See the meta question on [What to do about missing source attributions: Copying, Linking, Attributions, and Plagiarism](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4973) for discussion about this.

Answer (score 2):

**Day** is the English term for the 24 hour period of a calendar.  **Night** is the dark part, and **Daytime** is the light part.  Daytime is then shortened to Day when the context is clear which you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

*Day* is one of the time extent words that have both Calendric and Non-Calendric senses. The non-calendric sense refers to any 24-hour period, regardless of starting point, while the calendric sense goes like calendar numbering, from midnight to midnight. So *day* is the right word, provided it's used in the right constructions.

As Fillmore explains it in the [Deixis Lectures](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Deixis.html):

> "When nature provides sequentially recurring event types having apparently the same duration, these event types can be used to provide measuring units for temporal extent. The recurring event types that are most constant and most common and most accessible to ordinary observers are the daily alternation of light and dark, changes in how the moon looks to us, and the apparent annual course of the sun accompanied by the regularly recurring changes in the seasons.
>
> "These particular event types are cycles which do not involve the sequencing of discrete separable events, and so, when they are used for providing units of measure, it is necessary to identify recurrences of the **same phase** of the cycle. Those phases which seem to have constant temporal extenst between successions of them are, for example, the full moon, the most vertical position of the sun, the shortest day of the year, etc.
>
> "If these cycles are to be taken only as units of measure, it makes no difference which phase of the cycle is taken as the starting point for the measurement. If, however, these events are to provide concepts for locating events in *"absolute time"*, then there is a special need for **fixed-phase** units, time units which have been assigned fixed starting points recognizable, in principle, by all members of the speech community. Time measure periods taken only as units of measure we can call **Non-Calendric**. Time measure periods having fixed starting points can be called **Calendric**.
>
> "Many of the time measure words in English have both calendric and non-calendric uses,
>   for example, the word *year*. If I say that the time between noon on June 28, 1972 and
>   noon on June 28, 1973 is one year, I am using the word *year* non-calendrically. On
>   the other hand, if I use the expression *last year*, meaning the period of time between 
>   the beginning of January 1, 1970 and the end of December 31, 1970, I am using the word 
>   *year* in its calendric sense."

- *from* [Lecture 3: *Time*](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/3-Time.pdf), pp 33-4

Comment: Consider children who are allowed to play outside by day but not by night, or people who work the day shift versus those who work the night shift. In other words, what about the kind of *day* that is the opposite of *night*?  That kind of *day*  fits neither of your two definitions as far as I can tell, which seems to show that they do not together define all possible sorts of time. When I work all day, I assure you I do not work 24 hours!

Comment: That's simply a modified sense of _day_ for a special purpose, just as _car_ in the sense of _cattle car_ is a special use of the word for _automobile_. Fillmore is trying to explain the basic concepts these special uses come from. If he tried to explain all the variation, he'd never finish.