# Meaning of 'within' in "the task has to be submitted within a month"

Tags: prepositions, word-usage, range-inclusion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Within” and “in” when referring to time](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95697/within-and-in-when-referring-to-time)

if there's a sentence :

> The task has to be submitted within a month

Does it mean that the task has to be submitted *before* a month or can we submit it exactly a month after the task was announced?

eg. The task was announced on jan 1

Comment: I would get clarification from whoever wrote that as to exactly what they mean. Does it mean *within the month of January* or does it mean within (a typical month length) 30-31 days of the announcement. Only the person who wrote it can really give you the answer as to what they mean.

Comment: @spiceykooko okay, what about within a week?

Comment: That would depend on whether you mean *working week* Monday to Friday or *calendar week* Monday to Sunday!

Comment: @spiceyokooko calendar week, and the task was announced on monday. can we submit it next monday?

Comment: In my opinion (and it is only my opinion) I would say it needs to be submitted within a working week - so last thing on Friday. Within means inside a week, so if you you're talking working week it would be *inside* those 5 workings days - Monday – Friday. If it's *inside* a calendar week it would need to be *inside* 7 calendar days – Monday to Sunday. If you're submitting on Monday it's *outside* a week.

Comment: Use the expression **only** where the distinction is **not** expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the task has to be submitted at any time before the expiry of the month.

Comment: so we can't submit it on feb 1?

Comment: @stargirl. It depends on when the month is deemed to have started.

Answer (score 1):

*Within a month* is an inexact specification and shares the same ambiguity as other similar statements such as *before a month*, *before 31<sup>st</sup> January*, etc. [ODO's relevant definition](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/within) reads:

> occurring **inside** (a particular period of time):
>   *tickets were sold out within two hours
>
>   33 per cent offended again within two years of being released*

There's also the question of the number of days signified by ***a** month*. Months can be 28, 29, 30, or 31 days long.