# What does it mean: A utility hookup or work order dated within 60 days before registration?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, phrase-meaning, legalese, sentence-meaning

Does it mean any day in a timeframe of 60 days max to the action, in other words: it could be 1 day or 59 days before?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Within" and "in" when referring to time](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95697/within-and-in-when-referring-to-time)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does. It means “60 days or less prior to registration” (which would be a more clear sentence).